# Concatenate value of 2 columns datatable with space and replace "-" with empty in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, replace, datatable, datagridview, concatenation

I'm trying to Concatenate value of 2 columns datatable with space and replace "-" with empty in vb.net.

I have the code below, but this is still wrong.

please guide me

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Example - Expression Column
        Dim dt = New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("A", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("B", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("C", GetType(String), "CONVERT(A, System.String)+ B")
        dt.Rows.Add("BALOTELLY", "OLD WARDAH (02)")
        dt.Rows.Add("TOYOBO FODU THOMPSON", "LIGHT BLACK (12)")
        dt.Rows.Add("MCR", "-")
        dt.Rows.Add("WALLY COTTON CREAP", "-")
        dt.Rows.Add("WALLY COTTON CREAP", "BLACK (23)")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: RESULT IN DATAGRIDVIEW]

DESIRED RESULT

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BALOTELLY | OLD WARDAH (02) | BALOTELLY OLD WARDAH (02) |
| TOYOBO FODU THOMPSON | LIGHT BLACK (12) | TOYOBO FODU THOMPSON LIGHT BLACK (12) |
| MCR | - | MCR |
| WALLY COTTON CREAP | - | WALLY COTTON CREAP |
| WALLY COTTON CREAP | BLACK (23) | WALLY COTTON CREAP BLACK (23) |

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression) for the `DataColumn.Expression` property? Everything that you can do is listed and described there. Show us what you tried and tell us what happened when you tried it.

Comment: @Jimi , 
Thank you for your response . 
I tried your suggestion but it still doesn't have spaces, did I implement the code wrong `dt.Columns.Add("C", GetType(String), Trim("CONVERT(A, System.String)+ B"))`

Comment: @jmcilhinney , 
Thank you for your advice, I'm still trying it. `CONVERT(A, System.String)+ B` 
I tried it until this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression to append `B` value if any and skip the `-` values.

```cs
"A + IIF(B Is Null Or SUBSTRING(B, 1, 1) = '-', '', ' ' + B)"
```

To apply that to `A` and `B`:

```cs
"TRIM(IIF(A Is Null Or SUBSTRING(A, 1, 1) = '-', '', A) + IIF(B Is Null Or SUBSTRING(B, 1, 1) = '-', '', ' ' + B))"
```

Comment: Sorry I replied late. Your answer is perfect . For columns `A` I coded it like this `dt.Columns.Add("C", GetType(String), "IIF(A Is Null Or SUBSTRING(A, 1, 1) = '-', '', ' ' + A) + IIF(B Is Null Or SUBSTRING(B, 1, 1) = '-', '', ' ' + B)")` .Is it correct? and but the result in the datagridview is appropriate