# Concatenate value of 2 columns datatable with update with one criteria expression in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, expression

I'm trying to Concatenate value of 2 columns datatable with update with one criteria expression in vb.net

So there are additional criteria, namely: `NO COLOR`
I have the code below, but this is still wrong.

please guide me

previously related to the previous link [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77546880/concatenate-value-of-2-columns-datatable-with-space-and-replace-with-empty-i/77547447#77547447)

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Public dt As DataTable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dt = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("A", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("B", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("C", GetType(String), "TRIM(IIF(A Is Null Or SUBSTRING(A, 1, 1) = '-', '', A) + IIF(B Is Null Or SUBSTRING(B, 1, 1) = '-', '', ' ' + B))")
  dt.Rows.Add("BALOTELLY", "OLD WARDAH (02)")
        dt.Rows.Add("TOYOBO FODU THOMPSON", "LIGHT BLACK (12)")
        dt.Rows.Add("MCR", "-")
        dt.Rows.Add("WALLY COTTON CREAP", "-")
        dt.Rows.Add("WALLY COTTON CREAP", "BLACK (23)")
        dt.Rows.Add("-", "-")
        dt.Rows.Add("WALLY COTTON CREAP", "NO COLOR")
        dt.Rows.Add("-", "NO COLOR")
        dt.Rows.Add("", "NO COLOR")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Dim CheckedBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
        CheckedBoxColumn.Width = 40
        CheckedBoxColumn.Name = "checkboxcolumn"
        CheckedBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Check"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, CheckedBoxColumn)
    End Sub
```

[image: RESULT IN DATAGRIDVIEW16122023]

DESIRED RESULT

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BALOTELLY | OLD WARDAH (02) | BALOTELLY OLD WARDAH (02) |
| TOYOBO FODU THOMPSON | LIGHT BLACK (12) | TOYOBO FODU THOMPSON LIGHT BLACK (12) |
| MCR | - | MCR |
| WALLY COTTON CREAP | - | WALLY COTTON CREAP |
| WALLY COTTON CREAP | BLACK (23) | WALLY COTTON CREAP BLACK (23) |
| - | - |  |
| WALLY COTTON CREAP | NO COLOR | WALLY COTTON CREAP |
| - | NO COLOR |  |
|  | NO COLOR |  |

Comment: Is this right? `A = -` and `B = -` outputs `WALLY COTTON CREAP BLACK (23)`. How? As for the `NO COLOR`, add one `Or` condition?  So, if `B` is null or the first char is `-` or `= NO COLOR`, then return null or empty string `''`.

Comment: @dr.null , thank you for your reply. `Is this right? A = - and B = - outputs WALLY COTTON CREAP BLACK (23)` this is my typo. `As for the NO COLOR, add one Or condition? So, if B is null or the first char is - or = NO COLOR, then return null or empty string ''`  meaning like this `IIF(B Is Null Or SUBSTRING(B, 1, 1) Or '= NO COLOR' = '-', '', ' ' + B)`

Comment: @dr.null , I managed to solve it with your suggestions into code like this `dt.Columns.Add("C", GetType(String), "TRIM(IIF(A Is Null Or SUBSTRING(A, 1, 1) = '-', '', A) + IIF(B Is Null Or SUBSTRING(B, 1, 1) = '-' Or B ='NO COLOR' , '', ' ' + B))")`

Comment: Correct. Good...

Comment: @dr.null , 
Thank you because you helped me and 
I have a new post maybe you can help me  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77689246/is-it-possible-to-make-animations-like-bunifu-transitions-with-toolbox-controls)