# Is it possible to generate animated transitions with standard Controls?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, animation, graphics, transition

Is it possible to make animations, like the transitions generated by Bunifu, with standard WinForms Controls in the VB.NET language?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PanelForm.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BunifuTransition1.Show(PanelForm)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        BunifuTransition1.Hide(PanelForm)
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: PROPERTIES BUNIFU TRANSITION]

[image: BUNIFU TRANSITION]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add some animation effects to a window (Controls are windows), you can use the Win32 [AnimateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow) function.
This function allows to generate some predefined effects: roll, slide, collapse or expand and alpha-blended fade (which can only be applied to a top-level window, though).

It's missing any effect that scale the content of the window, as shown in the question.
I've added this missing effect (along with the already supported ones) in an extension method, `Animate()` that is applied to all classes that derive from Control.
Which means you can also animate a Form that is not a top-level window (`.TopLevel = False`)

For example, to animate a Panel (and the Controls it hosts), write:

```
SomePanel.Animate(AnimationMode.OpenScale, 500)
```

to add an opening animation that lasts 500 milliseconds. Or, e.g.,

```
SomePanel.Animate(AnimationMode.CloseScale, 500)
```

to add a closing animation with the same duration.
Try out the other effects you can select, settings a different `AnimationMode`.

This is how it works:

[image: AnimateWindow Extension Method]

*The generated GIF animation makes it a little sluggish*

---

Add this Module to any WinForms Project.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module ExtensionMethods
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Add opening or closing effects to a Control
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="window">The Control to animate</param>
    ''' <param name="mode">The animation effect</param>
    ''' <param name="animationSpeed">The overall time, in milliseconds, of the animation</param>
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub Animate(window As Control, mode As AnimationMode, animationSpeed As Integer)
        If isAnimating Then Return
        isAnimating = True
        If mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.OpenScale) OrElse mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.CloseScale) Then
            AnimateScale(window, mode, animationSpeed)
        Else
            window.Show()
            If Not mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.Hide) Then window.Hide()
            AnimateWindow(window.Handle, CType(animationSpeed, UInteger), mode)
            If Not mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.Hide) Then window.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private isAnimating As Boolean = False
    Private animateBitmap As Bitmap = Nothing
    Private animateBitmapBounds As Rectangle = Rectangle.Empty

    Private Sub AnimateScale(window As Control, mode As AnimationMode, Optional animationSpeed As Integer = 200)
        Dim steps = 10
        If animationSpeed < 200 Then animationSpeed = 200
        Dim timerSteps = animationSpeed \ (steps + 1)
        Dim animationFrames As List(Of Bitmap) = Nothing

        Using bmpSource = New Bitmap(window.Width, window.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
            window.Show()
            window.DrawToBitmap(bmpSource, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, window.Size))
            window.Hide()
            animationFrames = GetAnimationFrames(steps, bmpSource, mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.CloseScale))
        End Using

        Dim windowParent = If(window.Parent Is Nothing, window, window.Parent)
        animateBitmapBounds = window.Bounds
        Dim timer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer() With {.Interval = timerSteps}
        AddHandler timer.Tick,
        Sub()
            If steps < 0 Then
                timer.Stop()
                RemoveHandler windowParent.Paint, AddressOf AnimateWindowParent
                animationFrames.ForEach(Sub(img) img.Dispose())
                animationFrames = Nothing
                animateBitmap = Nothing
                timer.Dispose()
                isAnimating = False
            Else
                animateBitmap = animationFrames(steps)
                windowParent.Invalidate(animateBitmapBounds)
                If steps = 0 AndAlso mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.OpenScale) Then window.Show()
            End If
            steps -= 1
        End Sub
        AddHandler windowParent.Paint, AddressOf AnimateWindowParent
        window.Hide()
        timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetAnimationFrames(framesCount As Integer, sourceImage As Image, collapse As Boolean) As List(Of Bitmap)
        Dim animationFrames As New List(Of Bitmap)(framesCount)
        Dim scaleWidth = sourceImage.Width \ framesCount
        Dim scaleHeight = sourceImage.Height \ framesCount

        For frame As Integer = 1 To framesCount
            Dim imageSize = New Size(sourceImage.Width - frame * scaleWidth, sourceImage.Height - frame * scaleHeight)
            Dim imagePos = New Point((sourceImage.Width - imageSize.Width) \ 2, (sourceImage.Height - imageSize.Height) \ 2)
            Dim imageFrame = New Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
            Using g = Graphics.FromImage(imageFrame)
                g.DrawImage(sourceImage, New RectangleF(imagePos, imageSize),
                            sourceImage.GetBounds(GraphicsUnit.Pixel), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
                If collapse Then
                    animationFrames.Insert(0, imageFrame)
                    If frame = framesCount Then animationFrames.Insert(0, New Bitmap(2, 2))
                Else
                    animationFrames.Add(imageFrame)
                    If frame = framesCount Then animationFrames.Add(New Bitmap(2, 2))
                End If
            End Using
        Next
        Return animationFrames
    End Function

    Private Sub AnimateWindowParent(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
        If animateBitmap Is Nothing Then Return
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(animateBitmap, animateBitmapBounds)
    End Sub

    <Flags()>
    Public Enum AnimationMode As UInteger
        CloseCentered = AW_CENTER Or AW_HIDE
        CloseDownwards = AW_VER_POSITIVE Or AW_HOR_POSITIVE Or AW_HIDE
        CloseUpwards = AW_VER_NEGATIVE Or AW_HOR_NEGATIVE Or AW_HIDE
        OpenCentered = AW_CENTER
        OpenDownwards = AW_HOR_POSITIVE Or AW_VER_POSITIVE
        OpenUpwards = AW_HOR_NEGATIVE Or AW_VER_NEGATIVE
        OpenScale = &H20
        CloseScale = &H40 Or Hide
        SlideToRight = AW_SLIDE Or AW_HOR_POSITIVE
        SlideToLeft = AW_SLIDE Or AW_HOR_NEGATIVE
        SlideDownwards = AW_SLIDE Or AW_VER_POSITIVE
        SlideUpwards = AW_SLIDE Or AW_VER_NEGATIVE
        Hide = AW_HIDE
    End Enum

    Private Const AW_HOR_POSITIVE As UInteger = &H1
    Private Const AW_HOR_NEGATIVE As UInteger = &H2
    Private Const AW_VER_POSITIVE As UInteger = &H4
    Private Const AW_VER_NEGATIVE As UInteger = &H8
    Private Const AW_CENTER As UInteger = &H10
    Private Const AW_HIDE As UInteger = &H10000
    Private Const AW_ACTIVATE As UInteger = &H20000
    Private Const AW_SLIDE As UInteger = &H40000
    Private Const AW_BLEND As UInteger = &H80000

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Function AnimateWindow(hwnd As IntPtr, time As UInteger, flags As AnimationMode) As Boolean
    End Function
End Module
```

---

**C# version, just in case**:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static void Animate(this Control window, AnimationMode mode, int animationSpeed) {
        if (isAnimating) return; 
        isAnimating = true;
        if (mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.OpenScale) || mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.CloseScale)) {
            AnimateScale(window, mode, animationSpeed);
        }
        else {
            window.Show();
            if (!mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.Hide)) window.Hide();
            AnimateWindow(window.Handle, (uint)animationSpeed, mode);
            if (!mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.Hide)) window.Show();
        }
    }

    private static bool isAnimating = false;
    private static Bitmap? animateBitmap = null;
    private static Rectangle animateBitmapBounds = Rectangle.Empty;

    private static void AnimateScale(Control window, AnimationMode mode, int animationSpeed = 200) {
        int steps = 10;
        if (animationSpeed < 200) animationSpeed = 200;
        int timerSteps = animationSpeed / (steps + 1);
        List<Bitmap>? animationFrames = null;

        using (var bmpSource = new Bitmap(window.Width, window.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)) {
            window.Show();
            window.DrawToBitmap(bmpSource, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, window.Size));
            window.Hide();
            animationFrames = GetAnimationFrames(steps, bmpSource, mode.HasFlag((Enum)AnimationMode.CloseScale));
        }

        var windowParent = window.Parent is null ? window : window.Parent;
        animateBitmapBounds = window.Bounds;
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = timerSteps };
        timer.Tick += (_, _) =>
        {
            if (steps < 0) {
                timer.Stop();
                windowParent.Paint -= AnimateWindowParent;
                animationFrames.ForEach(img => img.Dispose());
                animationFrames = null;
                animateBitmap = null;
                timer.Dispose();
                isAnimating = false;
            }
            else {
                animateBitmap = animationFrames[steps];
                windowParent.Invalidate(animateBitmapBounds);
                if (steps == 0 && mode.HasFlag(AnimationMode.OpenScale))
                    window.Show();
            }
            steps -= 1;
        };
        windowParent.Paint += AnimateWindowParent;
        window.Hide();
        timer.Start();
    }

    private static List<Bitmap> GetAnimationFrames(int framesCount, Image sourceImage, bool collapse) {
        var animationFrames = new List<Bitmap>(framesCount);
        var scaleWidth = sourceImage.Width / framesCount;
        var scaleHeight = sourceImage.Height / framesCount;

        for (int frame = 1, loopTo = framesCount; frame <= loopTo; frame++) {
            var imageSize = new Size(sourceImage.Width - frame * scaleWidth, sourceImage.Height - frame * scaleHeight);
            var imagePos = new Point((sourceImage.Width - imageSize.Width) / 2, (sourceImage.Height - imageSize.Height) / 2);
            var imageFrame = new Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(imageFrame)) {
                var unit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                g.DrawImage(sourceImage, new RectangleF(imagePos, imageSize), sourceImage.GetBounds(ref unit), unit);
                if (collapse) {
                    animationFrames.Insert(0, imageFrame);
                    if (frame == framesCount) animationFrames.Insert(0, new Bitmap(2, 2));
                }
                else {
                    animationFrames.Add(imageFrame);
                    if (frame == framesCount) animationFrames.Add(new Bitmap(2, 2));
                }
            }
        }
        return animationFrames;
    }

    private static void AnimateWindowParent(object? sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        if (animateBitmap is null) return;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(animateBitmap, animateBitmapBounds);
    }

    [Flags()]
    public enum AnimationMode : uint {
        CloseCentered = AW_CENTER | AW_HIDE,
        CloseDownwards = AW_VER_POSITIVE | AW_HOR_POSITIVE | AW_HIDE,
        CloseUpwards = AW_VER_NEGATIVE | AW_HOR_NEGATIVE | AW_HIDE,
        OpenCentered = AW_CENTER,
        OpenDownwards = AW_HOR_POSITIVE | AW_VER_POSITIVE,
        OpenUpwards = AW_HOR_NEGATIVE | AW_VER_NEGATIVE,
        OpenScale = 0x20U,
        CloseScale = 0x40U | Hide,
        SlideToRight = AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_POSITIVE,
        SlideToLeft = AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_NEGATIVE,
        SlideDownwards = AW_SLIDE | AW_VER_POSITIVE,
        SlideUpwards = AW_SLIDE | AW_VER_NEGATIVE,
        Hide = AW_HIDE
    }

    #region NativeMethods

    private const uint AW_HOR_POSITIVE = 0x1U;
    private const uint AW_HOR_NEGATIVE = 0x2U;
    private const uint AW_VER_POSITIVE = 0x4U;
    private const uint AW_VER_NEGATIVE = 0x8U;
    private const uint AW_CENTER = 0x10U;
    private const uint AW_HIDE = 0x10000U;
    private const uint AW_ACTIVATE = 0x20000U;
    private const uint AW_SLIDE = 0x40000U;
    private const uint AW_BLEND = 0x80000U;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AnimateWindow(IntPtr hwnd, uint time, AnimationMode flags);

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: your answer is perfect .  for this code `SomePanel.Animate(AnimationMode.OpenScale, 500)` for this code, the speed animation results are the same as bunifu transition by changing the speed  `SomePanel.Animate(AnimationMode.OpenScale, 200)`
become `

Comment: Scale animation may only work for panels but for forms it may not work. If possible then I will make a new post for you

Comment: It works if the Form is not a top-level window (you have set `.TopLevel = false`). If it's a top-level window, you'd have to paint the transition directly on the current Screen's Device Context (see the last paragraph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103)). Not impossible, but quite outside the scope of the question

Comment: BTW, I've changed the code a little, to prevent a new animation from being triggered when one is already being performed, since it doesn't look very good

Comment: Thank you for your update and I made a recent post related to the scale transition animation form . [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77701485/is-it-possible-to-generate-animated-transitions-with-form-in-vb-net)