# Is it possible to generate animated transitions with Form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, animation, graphics, transition

Is it possible to make animations, like the transitions generated by Bunifu, with form in the VB.NET language?

Previously related to the link below with standard Controls
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77689246/is-it-possible-to-generate-animated-transitions-with-standard-controls/77693753?noredirect=1#comment136979757_77693753)

Code in form1

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim f2 As New Form2()
        f2.Animate(AnimationMode.OpenScale, 200)
        f2.TopLevel = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: animated transitions with form]

Comment: As mentioned before, if you want to animate a Form by scaling it, you have to turn it into a non-top-level window and add it to the Controls collection of a container. Of course, before you call the `Animate()` method. You cannot animate a top-level window like that, unless you're willing to generate graphics on the current Screen's DC. That can be done, as also mentioned (last paragraph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103)). Or hide it and replace it with a per-pixel-alpha Form, scaling its content

Comment: You can also use one of the other effects that apply to top-level windows, as the `Blend` effect (`AW_BLEND` or `AW_BLEND` + `AW_HIDE`). Give it a shot

Comment: @Jimi , 
Thank you for your response. Can you answer as an answer so that I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible without Bunifu.

WinForms uses GDI+ which is drawn be the CPU and therefore might be not as smooth as GPU rendered UIs. But it works pretty well if you do intelligent frame smoothing.

That's what [Richard S. Shepherd started on Google Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/dot-net-transitions/). I built upon this unmaintained code and improved on it to build [FluentTransitions](https://github.com/awaescher/FluentTransitions) for new .NET versions.

[image: Animation]

I cannot really see what kind of animation you wanted to achieve in your gif, so here's an animation that can animate the form width from 0 to a desired value within 200 milliseconds:

```cs
Transition
    .With(myForm, nameof(Form.Width), maxWidth) // target, property, value
    .EaseInEaseOut(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)); // method and duration
```

**Fun fact:**
Bunifu took their animation logic from this repository, too.

[image: Bunifu]